# Bounty reputation

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Do you get your reputation back if nobody posts new comments or answers to the question you have set a bounty on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If no answers meet these criteria, the bounty ends without it being awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter."

Taken from the top answer from this question: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)